# How to replace all "slash" division expressions with \frac{}{}?

Tags: math-mode, fractions

Is there a way to autoreplace  `.../...` with `\frac{...}{...}`?

For example, `143/23` should be rendered as `\frac{143}{23}`

Comment: It is possible (but fragile) to do this sort of replacement in TeX  in simple cases (see the supplied answer) but it is really much better to use your text editor to do the replacement in the document source.

Comment: The main problem is, how is one supposed to "know" where the numerator starts and where the denominator ends? Is it safe to assume that the numerator and the denominator will always consist purely of digits and that there will be no nested fraction terms?

Comment: @Mico Yes, there are one digit in numerator and one in denumerator.

Comment: One might also ask *why* you're doing this. In inline text, it's very often preferable to have slashed fractions over stacked fractions. Even $1 / 2$ is easier to read than $\frac{1}{2}$, not even to mention such "complicated" cases as $\frac{x^2}{2}$.

Comment: @WChargin To be honest, in a table I used $1 / 2$ because of $frac{}{}$ and $dfrac{}{}$ version very ugly in table.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here's a LuaLaTeX-based solution. It works for all fractional expressions where both the numerator and the denominator contain only (one or more) digits, and it works both in inline-math and display-math modes. In order for `\frac` to work, the fractional terms must be in math-mode material. Only fractional expressions with digits are processed; expressions such as `a/b` will *not* be modified.

If you want "large" fractions throughout the document, be sure to load the `amsmath` package and change `frac` to `dfrac` in the Lua function below.

In case you're curious: The lua function `replace_slash` uses so-called captures to identify the numerator and denominator terms. The lua function is assigned to the `process_input_buffer` callback. This means that the function operates on the input *before* TeX starts its own processing. Thus, TeX's "eyes" will never even see an expression such as `$1/2$`; instead, they'll only get to see the expression `$\frac{1}{2}$`.

(Addendum 9 Nov 2015: Generalized the Lua code so that (i) signed integers (positive *or* negative) and (ii) any whitespace in the input are handled correctly.)

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{luacode} 

\begin{luacode}
function replace_slash ( line )
   return string.gsub ( line, "([%+%-]?%d+)%s-/%s-([%+%-]?%d+)", "\\frac{%1}{%2}" )
end
luatexbase.add_to_callback ( "process_input_buffer", replace_slash , "replace_slash" )
\end{luacode}

\begin{document}

How do we know that $55/110=1/2$?

\bigskip
$\displaystyle 55/110 = 1/2 $

\bigskip
Not modified: $a/(b+c)$, $x/y$, $2/x$
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum*: Allowing an optional factorial symbol, viz., `!`, in the numerator and/or denominator would be very easy: In the Lua function, simply replace the search string

```
   "([%+%-]?%d+)%s-/%s-([%+%-]?%d+)"
```

with

```
   "([%+%-]?%d+!?)%s-/%s-([%+%-]?%d+!?)"
```

In Lua's pattern matching jargon, `%s-` means "0 or more occurrences of whitespace", and the `!?` substring means "0 or 1 instance of `!`". With this modification, `$3! / 2!$` will be typeset as `$\frac{3!}{2!}$`.

Comment: @Mico luacode is still needed (or you could use \directlua but have to do something about `%`) My comment was perhaps a bit garbled, but anyway I'll remove both comments as the question is now edited

Answer (score 5):

There is TeX primitive `\over`. `\frac` is not the same, but the results in the basic case will be the same. Hence you can write

```
\catcode`\/=13
\def/{\over}
```

There are some disadvantages of making `/` an active character, but it is your choice.

MWE (please make them in the future) in your situation:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\catcode`\/=13
\def/{\over}

\[
143/23
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, I immediately get disadvantage. It's crash). Thank you anyway

Comment: @Simankov Hence we ask for MWE, where the real case can be tested. In particular, if you have `/` in other meaning than division, you should expect problem. But my MWE is working for you?

Comment: Yes, I wrap all my fractions in $$, and it is working now. But sizes of these fractions aren't good. They are so small compared to integer elements. Is there a way to fix it? I saw that dfrac{}{} looks better

Comment: @Simankov If you are using amstex, as I can guess,  I will recommend you rewritng you file and replacing `#1/#2` by `\frac{#1}{#2}` manually.

Comment: Okay. Really, I just must RTFM.I am like a monkey in latex now.

Comment: You may want to post a note that if the `amsmath` is loaded as well, the following warning message will be issued when `\over` is encountered: "Package amsmath Warning: Foreign command \over; \frac or \genfrac should be used instead."